# SKU custom column on sales order grid causing non-static issue

Tags: admin, grid, sales-order, filter

I have followed the guide [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/) by Volodymyr Vygovskyi, everything is working well, apart from when you filter by a sku, it causes the issue:

> Strict Notice: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method
>   Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer::filterSkus() should not be called
>   statically  in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mag19/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
>   on line 468

Investigating this I can see that he has the following as his filter_condition_callback:

```
'filter_condition_callback' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer', 'filterSkus'),
```

whereby the observer is being called statically here:

> 'Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer'

In my attempts to fix this, I changed this to the variable `$this`, which causes the filterSkus function to not be found.

Thus, I then attempted to move the filter function to the helper data.php file. This then led to the sku column in sales_flat_order_item to not be found.

Likewise also tried changing the string declaration of the observer to `Mage::getSingleton('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_model_observer')`. But, this then causes the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.sku' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE ((sales_flat_order_item.sku like '%lab%'))
```

I am at a loggerhead with how to fix this issue, thus was hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this via the following:

1. changing the string declaration of the observer to 
    `Mage::getSingleton('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_model_observer')`
2. Added the following missing join to the `salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore` function:

   $select->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));